# Error in fetching a list of urls from a website using anemone

Tags: ruby, anemone

Code:

```
require 'anemone'
Anemone.crawl("http://www.example.com/") do |anemone|
  anemone.on_every_page do |page|
    puts page.url
  end
end
```

When I try this code I should get a list of all the urls on that website but all I get is just the name of the website. What can possibly be the error and how do I get a list of all the urls?

Comment: It works fine. Obviously, if you do that on example.com, it will just display http://www.example.com as there is only this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess anemone just can't follow redirects or something like this, cause "http://example.com" redirects me on other site. Have you tried to crawl other sites? http://stackoverflow.com, for example.

Comment: This was just a proxy error and after setting the terminal proxy it is working fine.Is there any way to include proxy settings inside the script itself?

Comment: Sure, Anemone.crawl(url, {:proxy_host => 'your proxy host', :proxy_port => 'your proxy port'})

Comment: require 'anemone'
                                                                 Anemone.crawl("http://www.stackoverflow.com/") do |anemone|

     {:proxy_host => 'proxy.xyz.com', :proxy_port => '9999'}
 
        anemone.on_every_page do |page|
    
            puts page.url
        end
       end                                                                                                                                      tried this tto but it gives only the website name.